Why do we require intervals in Jensen's inequality?
In my notes I have

where $I$ is the interval on which $X$ takes values.  I am struggling to see why do we require for our random variable to be contained in an interval. I thought looking at the proof will show us why but I can't seem to find where it breaks. I am referencing page 29 of https://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Lectures/pm.pdf .
Question: Is it result still true for when $I= \mathbb R$ instead?

The theorem remains valid when $I= \mathbb R,$ in fact that is the more usual form in which it is stated. Your more general form comes in handy when you want to consider functions $f$ that are only convex (or even defined) on a connected proper subset of $\mathbb R,$ like the tangent on the interval $[0,\pi/2).$

I assume by interval the author allows for unbounded intervals, e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ is an interval. As you can see there are no problems in the proof if $I$ is interchanged with $\mathbb{R}$ or $[0,\infty)$. I think the importance of specifying that the domain of $f$ is an interval is that the definition of convexity of $f$ requires that its domain is connected, so that for each $t\in (0,1)$, $x,y \in I$, $tx+ (1-t)y \in I$.
